# Bad Request: message text is empty when sending get request via winapi to telegram bot

Tags: c++, winapi, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send message to telegram chat from bot using winapi and c++.
Here is my code

```
char szData[1024];

// initialize WinInet
HINTERNET hInternet = ::InternetOpen(TEXT("WinInet Test"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hInternet != NULL)
{
    // open HTTP session
    HINTERNET hConnect = ::InternetConnect(hInternet, L"api.telegram.org", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, NULL, 1);
    if (hConnect != NULL)
    {
        wstring request = L"/bot<bot_id>/sendMessage";

        // open request
        HINTERNET hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", (LPCWSTR)request.c_str(), NULL, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 1);
        if (hRequest != NULL)
        {
            // send request
            const wchar_t* params = L"?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=test";
            BOOL isSend = ::HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0, (LPVOID)params, wcslen(params));

            if (isSend)
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    // reading data
                    DWORD dwByteRead;
                    BOOL isRead = ::InternetReadFile(hRequest, szData, sizeof(szData) - 1, &dwByteRead);

                    // break cycle if error or end
                    if (isRead == FALSE || dwByteRead == 0)
                        break;

                    // saving result
                    szData[dwByteRead] = 0;
                }
            }

            // close request
            ::InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
        }
        // close session
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    }
    // close WinInet
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}

wstring answer = CharPToWstring(szData);

return answer;
```

But I've got `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}` response. `<chat_id>` is id consisted of digits(12345678).
If I run this request in postman or in browser - then everything is ok.
I also tried to run this request using `WinHttp*` methods and result is the same.
What should I change in my request parameters to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this code:

- You don't need to typecast the return value of `wstring::c_str()` to `LPCWSTR` (aka `const wchar_t*`), as it is already that type.
- You can't send body data in a `GET` request. The [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) expects body data to be sent in a `POST` request instead.
- You are telling `HttpSendRequest()` to send body data from a `wchar_t*` UTF-16 string, but that is not the correct encoding that the server is expecting. You need to use a `char*` UTF-8 string instead.
- You are not sending a `Content-Type` request header to tell the server what the format of the body data is. The API supports several different formats.  In this case, since you are sending the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, you need to add a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header to the request.

With all of that said, try this instead:

```
// initialize WinInet
HINTERNET hInternet = ::InternetOpenW(L"WinInet Test", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hInternet == NULL) ... // error handling

// open HTTP session
HINTERNET hConnect = ::InternetConnectW(hInternet, L"api.telegram.org", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, NULL, 1);
if (hConnect == NULL) ... // error handling

// open request
wstring wsResource = L"/bot<bot_id>/sendMessage";
HINTERNET hRequest = ::HttpOpenRequestW(hConnect, L"POST", wsResource.c_str(), NULL, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 1);
if (hRequest == NULL) ... // error handling

// send request
string sBody = u8"chat_id=<chat_id>&text=test";
BOOL isSend = ::HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", -1L, sBody.c_str(), sBody.size());
if (!isSend) ... // error handling

string sReply;
char szData[1024];
DWORD dwByteRead;

while (::InternetReadFile(hRequest, szData, sizeof(szData), &dwByteRead) && dwByteRead != 0)
{
    // saving result
    sReply.append(szData, dwByteRead);
}

...

// use sReply as needed ...
```